# Javascript Date validation for Asp.net

Tags: javascript

if i want to validate date of in Text box like 11-jul-2009 using javascript as Per cluture then how can i do Pleas tell me if any body know that....?

I am using this function....

```
function isDate(obj)   
{          
    var retVal = false;
    var dteDate;
    /*  Check for mm/dd/yyy format  */
    obj1 = obj.split("/"); 
    obj1[0] = parseInt(obj1[0], 10)-1; //for javascript 0=>January!
    obj1[1] = parseInt(obj1[1], 10);
    obj1[2] = parseInt(obj1[2], 10);
    dteDate=new Date(obj1[2], obj1[0], obj1[1]);
    retVal = ((obj1[1]==dteDate.getDate()) && (obj1[0]==dteDate.getMonth()) && (obj1[2]==dteDate.getFullYear()));

    /*  Check for dd-mmm-yyy format  */
    if(retVal == false)
    {
        obj1 = obj.split("-");
        if (obj1.length<3) return false;
        var month = isDate.months[obj1[1].toLowerCase()];
        if (typeof month != "number") return false;

        obj1[0] = parseInt(obj1[0], 10);
        obj1[1] = parseInt(month, 10)-1; //for javascript 0=>January!
        obj1[2] = parseInt(obj1[2], 10);
        dteDate=new Date(obj1[2], obj1[1], obj1[0]);

        retVal=(obj1[0]==dteDate.getDate()) && (obj1[1]==dteDate.getMonth()) && (obj1[2]==dteDate.getFullYear());
    }
    return retVal;
}

isDate.months = {
jan: 0, feb: 1, mar: 2, apr: 3, may: 4, jun: 5,
jul: 6, aug: 7, sep: 8, oct: 9, nov: 10, dec: 11
};
```

in abouve function how can i used date validation as per Currrent culture like we are using 
fr-FR then its giving error to validate ....:(
so Plesa tell me what another way  to sloved this Problem ....?

Comment: Other possible duplicates: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661117/javascript-regexp-validating-date-problem>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777725/jquery-javascript-date-form-validation>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939802/date-validation-with-asp-net-validator>

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel; use [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)